# Creating wave interference in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, animation

I want to create a wave interference in Adobe After Effects, such as

. I've already started with a radio wave, as shown below.[image]
However, I'm not sure how to 
a) Make the wave interact with other layers, such as those below:
[image]
b) Make 2 waves interfere with each other

I'm using Adobe After Effects 15.1.1, and I have Trapcode.

Comment: If you precomp the radio waves you can have multiple wave generators using the additive transfer mode and they'll add to each other like real waves would, then use that to drive the trapcode form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this requires a 3D effect rather than a 2D effect like Radio Waves. You might be able to achieve something like this using Trapcode Form.

Adding a bit more detail:

Make a radio wave using a black background and white waves..  Make the white waves quite thick, and have the radio waves start on the left of the screen.

Precomp the radio waves into their own comp

Ini the outer comp, add a blur to make the waves fall off gently instead of being hard black/white transitions.

Duplicate the inner comp in the Project tab, to make a second unique version of the comp

Drag this second comp into your main comp

Edit the origin position of the second radio wave comp, so that the second one starts towards the right of the screen.

You should now have something like this:

[image: screengrab]

Make a new solid layer in your outer comp

Add Trapcode Form to it

Set it up using Strings, using settings as shown:

[image: screen2]

Key thing is to set the Displacement on the Z axis to correspond to the radio waves pre-comp you've made (and make the radio waves pre-comp invisible).

[image: screen3]

Comment: Hi, I've tried to my best to recreate some interference with Trapcode Form, but it's of no use; I can't get two "forms" to a) interact with each other b) interfere constructively/destructively. If you have another tips that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Dumb question, but how do I precomp the waves?

Comment: Select the layer you want to pre-compose.  Hold down cmd+shit+C on a mac.. more here:
  https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/precomposing-nesting-pre-rendering.html